# Confusion around multiple jQuery versions, .noConflict, and jQuery migrate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-migrate

I have a project that is a massive website, and I was brought in to make the website responsive. I went with bootstrap for the framework, and quickly ran into issues with the jQuery version being used (v1.8.2). I solved my issues in a development environment by adding the following script references:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

I using $.noConflict(); but I do not believe it was in the correct spot. I called it after the three script references (old jquery, new jquery and jquery migrate). When we built the website to a staging environment, I am getting several script errors.

I read other questions similar to this, and found the following code:

```
<script src='jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
<script>
  var jq162 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script>
  var jq191 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

This does not use the migrate script. I have also seen the opposite where .noConflict is not called and only the migrate script is used.

Is one method considered better than the other? Or do I need to use both?

Comment: can you be more detailed on `I am getting several script errors` ? show one or some of those errors please. and did you read some of this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ ?

Comment: Sure, here's an example: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webkit' of undefined

Comment: I did read the jquery documentation for noconflict, and it seemed to be a little different than the way it was used in the answers I found on StackOverflow. It seems to call the newer jQuery first, then the older version. Would this be preferred?

Comment: `noConflict()` has nothing to do with newer or older versions of `jQuery` but why should I tell if read the docs ... while reading this https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/ I would just load `ONE` jQuery version and the migrate ...

Comment: @caramba thank you for your answer. I see that jQuery migrate only uses ONE version, then calls the migrate script. I am concerned that removing the first reference will cause errors, but I will test that next. It seems noConflict() does have to do with the newer or older versions though. Why else would the above code (from the question I found) be used?

Comment: maybe that's a way of how you can use two jQuery versions at the same time. noConflict() make's you "a new `$`" so they don't conflict each other cause theyre like in a global scope

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So based on that, noConflict absolutely has to do with the newer/older versions of jQuery.

Comment: Noo you missed the `.` at my comment before. noConflict is here to use different libraries which use a `$`. So if you use lets say prototype and jQuery then you must use noConflict. About how to use different jQuery versions read the migrate link mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

`NoConflict` function isn't for these purpose. The `NoConflict` is used to skip from conflict between JQuery and others frameworks with use the `$` shortcut, like the Prototype framework. Conflict between diferents JQuery must be resolved used one of them and removing the other (with preference keep the newest).